# Ramda, array equality regardless of order

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

When comparing arrays, the ramda `equals` will return true only if two arrays hold the same values in the same order.

I need a function to check if two arrays hold exactly the same values, but ignore the order in which the values occur.

For now I am doing it this way:

```
const equalLength = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.length === arr2.length

export const equalIgnoreOrder = (arr1, arr2) =>
  equalLength(arr1, arr2) && equalLength(arr1, R.union(arr1, arr2))
```

but I am wondering if there is a more 'out of the box' solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your answer is fine.  A slightly shorter one would be

```
const equalIgnoreOrder = compose(isEmpty, symmetricDifference)
```

This feels a bit more logical to me, as checking for the same elements feels more like a question of differences than unions; it feels closer to the mathematical idea of sets than does one that involves `length`.  But that's a pretty minor concern here.

Comment: thank you, I agree that `union` doesn't feel quite right here, that's what prompted me to ask the question. I had a version using `difference`, but it, as does yours, would match [1, 2, 3] and [1, 1, 2, 3]. Thinking in sets, that shouldn't be a problem, but for my use case such a state (duplicates) would indicate an error in my program.  Then again, I should probably guard/validate against duplicates at the time the arrays get populated, and not when I am comparing them.

Comment: While Ramda doesn't provide a public `Set` implementation, there is an [internal version](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/internal/_Set.js) which may serve s a model for how to deal with value equality for Sets.

Comment: I like it, very clean and simple

Comment: why not just using sort? `equals(arrayA.sort(), arrayB.sort())`?